# Selecionar o checkbox da linha ao clicar na linha

Tags: php, table

**Como faço ao selecionar uma linha e quando clicar, o checkbox for marcado?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                <!--tr behaviour="app.behaviours.panel"
                data-panel-action="show"
                data-panel-href="<?php // echo $this->Html->url(['action' => 'update', $user['User']['code']]); ?>"
                -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            $this->App->setattribute('type', 'checkbox');
                            $this->App->setattribute('toggle', 'User.id');

                            if ($user['User']['id'] == '1' or $user['User']['id'] == '2') {
                                $this->App->setattribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                            }

                            echo $this->App->createinput(false, 'toggle.' . $user['User']['id']);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $user['User']['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user['User']['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user['User']['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Tentou usar o label?

Comment: Não precisa ser. Só quero o .js pegando uma classe em <tr> e aplicando a cada linha o javascript